# Symfony2 and Disqus with KnpDisqusBundle

Tags: symfony, disqus

I've already used Disqus to add comments in a website before, but now I'm using Symfony2 and I'm intending to integrate Disqus with https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpDisqusBundle.

The documentation requires a public key and a secret key and to have them, I need to create a Disqus application. I tried to read the documentation of Disqus application to find out more about it (http://disqus.com/api/docs/), but with what I got, I can't I know more about Disqus application.

Googling so far didn't give me better results. 
I'd highly appreciate if someone could tell me more about Disqus Applications, what they are useful for, what are their functionalities and how to create them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would sign up for an API application here: http://disqus.com/api/applications/

Then you'll be assigned a secret key. To get a public key, you'll have to enter at least one whitelisted domain in your application settings after you set it up. Just make sure all the domains you're setting your site up on are included in that list.